# How to quarantine or delete infected files with ClamAV?

Tags: security, antivirus, clamav

I scanned the home directory using ClamAV which found 13 threats.
The list was also displayed, but when I tried to delete or quarantine files, it did not proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post a list with the files that Clamav (which searches for ***windows*** threats) assumed as threats?

Comment: the next time scanning revealed no threats, hence i am not able to show you the threats, sorry.

Comment: however i dont know hoe to scn the pendrive or other devices?

Answer (score 22):

You can use `clamscan` with the option `--remove` to automatically remove all infected file in the scanned folder. **WARNING**: Files are gone.

```
clamscan -r --remove /home/USER
```

Another possibility is to move the infected files to another folder with the option `--move=FOLDER`, so you can later check which files of them maybe not infected or a virus.

```
clamscan -r --move=/home/USER/VIRUS /home/USER
```

**See:** [How do I scan for viruses with ClamAV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav/)

Answer (score 1):

Once the scan is finished, a window should pop up listing the threats.  You have to actively select (click on) each threat you want deleted, then click on the delete or quarantine buttons.  Simply clicking "delete" without selecting a file will do nothing, which is what you've run into. To select all, click on the top file, scroll to the bottom of the list, and shift-click on the last file.  Then clicking quarantine or delete will process everything found.  You will get confirmation windows popping up for deleting certain things like .pdf files.