# How to cleanup a virus from a pen drive using ubuntu and recovering hidden files

Tags: antivirus

How do l recover hidden files on a pen drive,infected by a virus, as well as cleaning up the virus using ubuntu operating system

Comment: Why is this tagged virtualbox? And do you know what virus it is? Does it have Windows files or Linux files?

Comment: Ubuntu can not clean viruses. The only option for all the linux antivirus tools is to delete the files, no option to clean or remove the virus

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge none of the linux (Ubuntu) antivirus tools will remove viruses from infected files. The only options ate to delete or quarantine the files. You can not remove the virus from infected files to clean the files in any way.

Your best option is to identify the virus or viruses or other malware and then Google search for recovery options.

One of many tools is clamav. For information on how to use clamav see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

[How to quarantine or delete infected files with ClamAV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171441/how-to-quarantine-or-delete-infected-files-with-clamav)