# How to selectively delete infected files

Tags: security, malware

clamscan found these infected files:

/home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib64/wine/wordpad.exe: Win.Packed.Pwsx-9885269-0 FOUND

/home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib64/wine/dpnsvr.exe: Win.Malware.Malwarex-9883756-0 FOUND

/home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib/wine/wordpad.exe: Win.Packed.Pwsx-9885269-0 FOUND

/home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib/wine/dpnsvr.exe: Win.Malware.Malwarex-9883756-0 FOUND

How do I delete these files? I have tried clamscan -r --remove /home/USER but it went on for hours and I do not like the fact that I cannot choose selectively which files to delete. I also read online that one gets a window if clamscan detects infected files and that you can via this windows delete the infected files, but this does not occur for me.  If you say that I should not or need not delete these I still want to now for the future on how to selectively delete infected files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete file(s) in secure manner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57572/how-to-delete-files-in-secure-manner). This is probably not even necessary. You can "selectively" delete files by using the `rm` command followed by the path. Or you can just select them in your file manager and choose "delete" from the context menu, or use the `DEL` key.

Comment: It does not really answer my question, or maybe it does. Is this correct usage of rm: 
rm /home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib64/wine/wordpad.exe ? 
And what about "shred" is that better for deleting infected files?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a false positive?

Comment: It could be a false positive but as you see in my question I still want to know how to selectively delete the infected files that clamav finds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quarantine or delete infected files with ClamAV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171441/how-to-quarantine-or-delete-infected-files-with-clamav)

Comment: Sadly it does not answer my question Karel. As I wrote in the question "I have tried clamscan -r --remove /home/USER but it went on for hours and I do not like the fact that I cannot choose selectively which files to delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one (or, save all these lines in a script file and execute it) to delete the files.

```
rm /home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib64/wine/wordpad.exe

rm /home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib64/wine/dpnsvr.exe

rm /home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib/wine/wordpad.exe

rm /home/ludvig/.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/common/Proton 6.3/dist/lib/wine/dpnsvr.exe
```